# Login authentication Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have created authentication using ASP.NET,
But I am not getting how to check user is logged in or not before redirection to other pages
Please help me..

Thank you.
ManojKumar

Comment: [How ASP.NET Security Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks310b8y.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

For more info check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx